# Dropbox private Shared Folder

Tags: dropbox

My wife has a Dropbox she uses to exchange files (mainly pictures) with a friend, but needs to send files to a printer who uses Dropbox.

How can she create a Folder to privately share only with the printer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you will do it

1. Create two different folders ( Printer & Pictures) on your System/mobile sync with Drop box.
2. Go to Drop Box> Sign in>  Check the folders ( Printer & Pictures)  you just synced from desktop/mobile
3. Click on share link for printer folder to share it to only "printer folder"  put email of the required person and hurray !!

let me know if you get stuck.